# Inaccurate count when using multiple count functions in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, count

PostgreSQL 8.0.2 on i686-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 3.4.2 20041017 (Red Hat 3.4.2-6.fc3), Redshift 1.0.890

I'm relatively new to SQL and am learning a lot of about writing queries as in my current work role. I encountered this problem that puzzles me. If I do a count of subscriptions that are paid with a null churn date, I get a count of 1279. This is the correct number. But once I add the count of customers that installed shopify, this count jumps to 1835. Why would this happen? Can anybody help me out? Thanks!

```
select 
    count (s.account_id)
  , count (case when c.type ilike 'shopifychannel' and s.status = 'paid' 
                then c.created_at else null end) as installed_shopify
from subscriptions s
join channels c on s.account_id = c.account_id
where s.status = 'paid' 
  and s.churned_at is null
```

Count s.id will count the total number of customers who have s.status = 'paid'
Count case when 'shopifychannel' will count the total number of customers who have paid and installed a shopify channel. These are the outputs I am attempting to get.

Comment: Please show the original query as well as the new one. If possible, `explain analyze` output for both too. What's your PostgreSQL version? `SELECT version()`. **Edit the question** to add this info, then comment here when done.

Comment: If you have PostgreSQL 9.4 (or higher), then you should look into the `filter` clause on your aggregate expressions.

Comment: Alright. I made the edits. From my understanding, using case when will only count the cases when they have installed shopify. I am using "case when" because the rest of my query will count cases when they installed "amazon", etc. (other sales channels)

Comment: @LucasNeo no, you did not answer Craig's questions at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you have a problem with your `channels` table that may return more than one row per s.account_id. I propose this query :

```
SELECT 
    COUNT (DISTINCT s.account_id),
    COUNT (DISTINCT CONCAT(s.account_id, c.type)) AS installed_shopify
FROM subscriptions s
LEFT JOIN channels c ON s.account_id = c.account_id AND c.type ILIKE 'shopifychannel'
WHERE s.status = 'paid'
  AND s.churned_at IS NULL
```

Again, you must be sure that there is only (zero or one) row in channels for each account_id having the condition `c.type ilike 'shopifychannel'`.

The `LEFT JOIN` assure you don't miss a row in your primary table `subscriptions`. The condition `c.type ILIKE 'shopifychannel'` is in the LEFT JOIN because if you put it in the `WHERE` clause, you'll also lose `subscriptions` lines that don't have installed Shopify.

Comment: If there is more than 1 row, for some account_id having `c.type ilike 'shopifychannel'` then this would increase the count of `s.account_id` correct? Running this query gave me a `s.account_id` count of 1335. This number is higher but from my understanding it is because some `s.account_id` do have more than 1 row for `shopifychannel`.

Comment: You're right. I was supposing that there would be only zero/one line for shopifychannel. Let me think about that. (;

Comment: I modified the query so it takes in account the fact that a paid user can install the application multiple times.

Comment: it worked, thanks! I like your use of the CONCAT() function and I think its a good method for counting the distincts from 2 variables.

Comment: Glad it works ! (;